# Google maps rectangle bounds with Jquery and AJAX

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, google-maps

I try to retrieve data of rectangle bounds that I want to show as zones on Google maps. I collect data from database via AJAX with Jquery. This is what I have:

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/gui/templates/tracking/show_zones.php',
                //data: 'userid='+ uid ,
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(json) {
                    data=json;

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    {
                        showZone(data[i].nelat,data[i].swlat,data[i].nelng,data[i].swlng);
                    }    
                }
     });
```

and showZone function:

```
function showZone(north,south,east,west) {
      var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      bounds: {
             north: north,
             south: south,
             east: east,
             west: west
      }
   });

}
```

So data is recieved perfectly, for data[i].nelat, data[i].swlat, data[i].nelng, data[i].swlng I get values 46.187180 45.950665 14.795084 14.425919, which is correct. If i manually type this numbers in bounds variables I get a nice rectangle on the desired area. However, if I use this code i get an error:

'InvalidValueError: setBounds: not a LatLngBounds or LatLngBoundsLiteral: in property south: not a number'

The numbers are stored in database as float(10,6) which is corresponding to the Google's manual about PHP/mysql usage with maps. Do I still need to somehow cast numbers to a "proper" type or where could be the problem?

Comment: Are you testing this with the conversion into float? there could be an issue due to the json format.

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to parse bounds variables into floats :)